# Dynamically generate list of payment dates considering first/last date and client - ideal for controlling receivables of SaaS and recurrent contracts

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm building an accounts receivable sheet in Google Sheets.
I would like to register the clients and their contract characteristics (client, payment frequency and price) in one sheet and I would like to dynamically generate the payment dates in another sheet.

The input sheet would look like this:

[image]

The output sheet would look like this:

[image]

I think it might be something in the `QUERY` and `ARRAYFORMULA` universe but I don't know how to configure it. Is there a way to dynamically generate the combination of Date and Client, taking into consideration first and last payment dates?

[Sample in this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lOs4rtz0GSV5PXE4KDN7_rQXI-oTaFVNIH4KvZuoRYs/edit#gid=994959997). If you'd like to use, please fill free to create a copy for yourself and post it in your answer.

Comment: I would start with a unique list of clients then show those still unpaid. Unique() is a possibility.

Comment: Here is an editable sample copy created for this question that everyone can participate on.  It will automatically turn to View Only in 30 days.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pSanYmXXadAXllau2i6b1hy3Arln05o2lu08g22xDIk/edit#gid=0

Comment: Also, are the monthly and quarterly ones really by the day intervals you have? or are monthly, for example, supposed to be on the same day each month? 30 days (rather than truly monthly) will tend to work itself away from the correct month after a couple of years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a 2D array of concatenated strings of dates and values can be a good first step in these kinds of problems.

I've demonstrated the idea in a tab called MK.Help on [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pSanYmXXadAXllau2i6b1hy3Arln05o2lu08g22xDIk/edit#gid=75948094) that I also shared in the comment above.  This formula can be found in cell A2 and is generating the whole list:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Input!A2:A5&"|"&Input!D2:D5+SEQUENCE(1,CEILING(MAX(IFERROR((Input!E2:E5-Input!D2:D5)/Input!C2:C5))),0)*Input!C2:C5&"|"&Input!E2:E5),"|",0,0),"select Col2, Col1 where Col2<=Col3 order by Col2"))
```

Once you have the data in a big 2D array, you can flatten it out and then split it into it's component parts to make it query'able.  I've tried to outline the process to the right of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

@MattKing's answer was really good but I particularly had problems since all my inputs would have dynamic sizes and doing his step by step I couldn't figure how to adapt to this situation.

So, using a lot of Matt's inspiration and some extra research ([including this new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68263416/flatten-skipping-blank-cells-without-using-unique/68263577#68263577)) I came to a solution that worked better for me, using multiple pages to come to a final result. Not so classy but works.

[I left my solution available in this sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NXqV1BQLHeuTuCD8zxCgQt9QCcbSM-D-ondQx6kvpMs/edit#gid=1383724891)

Even though, I've chosen to accept Matt's answer since it worked, it helped me, it looks "more pythonic" and maybe the need to be so dynamic wasn't so clear in the question.

Comment: you realize that all those steps are only for demonstration right? The entire thing is generated just by the one formula in A2

Comment: @MattKing I do realize, the problem in your solution when I applied to my real life problem is that it works pretty fine when you select 3 rows to work with but when I tried to select the whole column it showed up some #VALUE #VALUE... In the original sample sheet you can see my try with your solution considering full columns. Even though, the solution you came with is really classy, you are a ninja, kudos.

Comment: fixed in your first sample sheet.