# FLATTEN skipping blank cells without using UNIQUE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to turn an array into a single column without blank cells, considering that the input will always have some blank cells and that there might be repeated values. I'm trying to use `FLATTEN` but it keeps the blanks and UNIQUE would kill the repeated values, so I can't use.

I also thought about using something like `FLATTEN(QUERY(X:X, "select * WHERE col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 IS NOT NULL")` but number of columns might be dynamic so I can't say precisely which columns to use.

My input:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

[Sample sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16rBS7m6Q61RSrHQKP4L0Y3ePsHU6_AcsHqw--11VOAU/edit#gid=0)

Any clue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `QUERY` on the *outside*:

`=QUERY(FLATTEN(YOUR-RANGE-HERE),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null")`

I left an example in your spreadsheet, cell G2.

**UPDATE 2023**

One can now use the following new function:

`=TOCOL(YOUR-RANGE-HERE, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
=flatten(filter(A1:E10;not(isblank(A1:E10))))
```

or

```
=flatten(filter(A1:E10;len(A1:E10)))
```

or

```
=filter(flatten(A1:E10);len(flatten(A1:E10)))
```